# Django url path conflict

Tags: django, url, path, tags

I'm new to django and stackoverflow so I ask your help because I can't figure out how to solve this problem.

I'm doing a ecommerce website for educational purposes.

I'm trying to achieve a full path like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/category1/subcategory1/product1

or

http://127.0.0.1:8000/category2/subcategory2/subcategory3/product2

I want to call `productlistview` to list all the products in any category and `productdetailview` for every product.

What is happening is that django always calls `productlistview` even when I call `url 'store:product_detail'` and get's me the 404 error as it doesn't find the category with the product name.

I'm aware that django always stops in the in the first url that matches but I'm awarding a `name` but it doesn't work.

Here are my templates:

```
#index.html
{% recursetree menu_category %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'store:product_list' cat_slug=node.full_slug %}">{{ node.name }}</a>
    {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
        <ul class="children">
            {{ children }}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endrecursetree %}


#product_list.html
{% for item in product %}
        <a href="{% url 'store:product_detail' cat_slug=category.full_slug prod_slug=item.slug %}"><p>{{ item.name }}</p></a>
{% endfor %}


#urls.py
app_name = 'store'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<path:cat_slug>', productlistview, name='product_list'),
    path('<path:cat_slug><slug:prod_slug>', productdetailview, name='product_detail'),
]

#views.py
def productlistview(request, cat_slug):
    category_select = get_object_or_404(Category, full_slug=cat_slug)
    product_list = Product.objects.filter(
        category__in=Category.objects.get(full_slug=cat_slug).get_descendants(include_self=True))
    return render(request, "store/product_list.html", {
        'category': category_select,
        'product': product_list,
    })


def productdetailview(request, prod_slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=prod_slug)
    return render(request, "store/product_detail.html", {
        'product': product,
    })


#models.py
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    full_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    parent = TreeForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, related_name="children", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.name
        self.slug = defaultfilters.slugify(unidecode(value))
        self.full_slug = self.full_path()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    def full_path(self):
        full_path = ["/", self.slug]
        k = self.parent
        while k is not None:
            full_path.append('/')
            full_path.append(k.slug)
            k = k.parent
        return "".join(full_path[::-1])


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.name
        self.slug = defaultfilters.slugify(unidecode(value))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help me.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's mistake in your urls.py.

Try changing:

```py
path('<path:cat_slug>', productlistview, name='product_list'),
path('<path:cat_slug><slug:prod_slug>', productdetailview, name='product_detail'),
```

to

```py
path('<path:cat_slug>/', productlistview, name='product_list'),
path('<path:prod_slug>/', productdetailview, name='product_detail'),
```

or try a different approach using just the slug and then update your view accordingly

```py
# urls.py
path('product-by-category/<slug:slug>/', productlistview, name='product_list'),
path('product/<slug:slug>/', productdetailview, name='product_detail'),
```

It is worth considering refactoring your views into class based views. This helps you write less code and keeps it much cleaner.

Comment: Hello Karl, thank you for your reply. If I change '<path:cat_slug/>' to <slug:cat_slug>/' and '<path:prod_slug/>' to <slug:prod_slug>/'in urls.py it works but the url is only the slug and not the full_slug. When I change back to path always goes to the productlistview. I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Best Regards.

Comment: @pnsbf I have just updated my answer, hopefully the second approach will fix the issue.

Comment: Hello Karl, thank you very much for you support. I'll try the different approach. Best Regards.